# Record hdmi stream and incoming & outcoming mumble stream

Tags: gaming

I'm playing a lot with my friends and daily we encounter something extremely hilarious. I would like to save these moments so we could watch them later.

This is what I would like to achieve:

- Record HDMI stream with a 3rd party device so it doesn't lag my PC at all.
- Record what others say in mumble
- record what I say in mumble

Is there a device that can do this?

Comment: What kind of videocard do you have and are you on a laptop?

Comment: This sounds like a piece of software not hardware.

Comment: Could you tell us a little more about your setup so that we can get an idea of what your PC can already handle?  How much are you willing to spend on this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used mumble, (always encrypted communication), before but presumably the incoming audio is available on the headphone socket, (otherwise how could you hear it?).

I expect there is a setting to broadcast your audio locally too.

I spent a lot of effort on this about 5 years ago for a project I can't remember very now.  Anyway something like the following should work:

http://www.startech.com/uk/AV/Converters/Video/usb-3-0-video-capture-device-hdmi-dvi-vga~USB3HDCAP

- Seamless picture quality with USB 3.0 bandwidth enabling you to
  capture 1080p video at 60fps
- Record from virtually any device, with support for HDMI, DVI, VGA,
  and Component video input sources
- Supports 2-channel stereo audio (HDMI / RCA)

[image]

I've used lots of startech products, their support is good and they are reliable.